# Pandas DataFrames If else condition on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a Data frame as shown below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["john","peter","john","alex"],
    "height": [6,5,4,4],
    "shape": ["null","null","null","null"]
})
```

I want to apply this---
If name == john and height == 6 return shape = good else if height ==  4 return shape = bad else change the shape to middle
so the final Dataframe should look like this

```
  df = ({
        "name": ["john","peter","john","alex"],
        "height": [6,5,4,4],
        "shape": ["good","middle","bad","bad"]
    })
```

The only library I want to use is 'Pandas' and I do NOT want to use 'lambda' or 'NumPy'.
Thanks in advance for your time.
I will upvote your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `np.select`

```
import numpy as np

cond1=df.name.eq('john')&df.height.eq(6)
cond2=df.height.eq(4)
df['shape']=np.select([cond1,cond2],['good','bad'],'middle')
df
    name  height   shape
0   john       6    good
1  peter       5  middle
2   john       4     bad
3   alex       4     bad
```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(if condition, yes,no). In this case I have nested the method. 

df.shape=np.where(df['height']==6,'good',np.where(df['height']==4, 'bad','middle'))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the answer. Would you please add the condition? I said the condition is that if the Name== john and height == 6  but you only wrote one condition not both of them. @wwnde